# How can I prevent labels (geom_text) from overlapping on a stacked bar graph in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

Unfortunately I can't show the graph this text produces due to the confidential nature of my work, but I've tried several ways to prevent label overlap on a stacked bar graph in ggplot, but the labels keep overlapping. If someone could demonstrate with simple generated-data I would be very grateful.

I've tried this and still get overlap:

```
supRace <- ggplot(focalData1, aes(x = as.factor(Races), fill = supervisor, by = as.factor(Races))) + geom_bar(width = .5, stat = "count") +
  geom_text_repel(label = after_stat("prop"), size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), direction = "y", box.padding = unit(0.01, "lines")) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(.05,0), labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 18))
supRace
```

This also doesn't get rid of the overlap and pushes them horizontally so the edge bar labels are cut off:

```
supRace <- ggplot(focalData1, aes(x = as.factor(Races), fill = supervisor, by = as.factor(Races))) + geom_bar(width = .5, stat = "count") +
  geom_text(stat = 'prop', position = position_jitter(height = 5), vjust= "fill", size = 3, check_overlap = T) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(.05,0), labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 18))
```

And finally tried these using geom_text_repel() and it gives me the error that it requires a 'y' aesthetic in the geom_text_repel() function:

```
## 1)
supRace <- ggplot(focalData1, aes(x = as.factor(Races), fill = supervisor, by = as.factor(Races))) + geom_bar(width = .5, stat = "count") +
  geom_text_repel(label = after_stat("prop"), size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), direction = "y", box.padding = unit(0.01, "lines")) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(.05,0), labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 18))
supRace
## 2)
supRace <- ggplot(focalData1, aes(x = as.factor(Races), fill = supervisor, by = as.factor(Races))) + geom_bar(width = .5, stat = "count") +
  geom_text_repel(inherit.aes = TRUE, label = "prop", size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), direction = "y", box.padding = unit(0.01, "lines")) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(.05,0), labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 18))
supRace
## 3)
supRace <- ggplot(focalData1, aes(x = as.factor(Races), fill = supervisor, by = as.factor(Races))) + geom_bar(width = .5, stat = "count") +
  geom_text_repel(aes(x = Races, y = ..count.., label = "prop"), size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), direction = "y", box.padding = unit(0.01, "lines")) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(.05,0), labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 18))
supRace
## 4)
supRace <- ggplot(focalData1, aes(x = as.factor(Races), fill = supervisor, by = as.factor(Races))) + geom_bar(width = .5, stat = "count") +
  geom_text_repel(aes(x = Races, y = after_stat(count), label = "prop"), size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), direction = "y", box.padding = unit(0.01, "lines")) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(.05,0), labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 18))
supRace
```

I'm sure there are a few variations I'm forgetting, but I could really use some help. One thing to mention, the smallest bar has 7 in the bottom bar and 1 in the top bar, but I figured if I can create space between labels, I can just increase the space for much smaller bars.

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(focalData1)` in order to make your code reproducible.